# mysql group_concat and group by not working

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat

I have the following two tables (simplified):

**tblinvoices**

```
id  dateCreated    

1   2020-01-02
2   2020-01-03
3   2020-01-03
4   2020-01-04
```

**tblinvoicesLines**

```
id invoiceId vatId vatAmount
1  4         7     35.50
2  4         8     15.75
3  4         7     11.50
3  5         7     10.05
4  6         7     11.04
```

I am trying to aggregate the vatAmount results in the output, like for this example:

```
invoiceId   listVatAmounts
4          47.00,15.75
5          10.05
6          11.04
```

I have the following mysql query:

```
select
tblInvoices.id as invoiceId,

(
select group_concat(vatAmount) from tblinvoicesLines
where tblinvoicesLines.invoiceId=tblInvoices.id
group by tblinvoicesLines.vatId
) as listVatAmounts

from tblInvoices
order by id desc
limit 10
```

I was hoping the **group by tblinvoicesLines.vatId** would group these values together, but mysql returns an error:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

What can I do to achieve the desired result? I want it to be achieved via a subquery.

Comment: It seems like you just need one table to do that > `tblinvoicesLines`

Comment: 'I want it to be achieved via a subquery' - why? And group_Concat alone is inappropriate since you appear to be summing the vat amounts by vatid first

Comment: Why do you group by vatId

Comment: You want an aggregation (comma-separated VAT list per invoice) of an aggregation (VAT sum per invoice and VAT ID). That is two steps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to perform the sums by `vatId` first, and then you can list the `vatAmount` sums by `invoiceId`:

```
SELECT invoiceId, GROUP_CONCAT(sumVatAmounts) AS listVatAmounts
FROM (SELECT invoiceId, vatId, SUM(vatAmount) AS sumVatAmounts
      FROM tblinvoicesLines
      GROUP BY invoiceId, vatId) t
GROUP BY invoiceId
```

Output:

```
invoiceId   listVatAmounts
4           47.00,15.75
5           10.05
6           11.04
```

If you need to include values from `tblInvoices`, you can just `JOIN` that table to the above query as a derived table:

```
SELECT i.id AS invoiceId, i.dateCreated, GROUP_CONCAT(t.sumVatAmounts) AS listVatAmounts
FROM tblInvoices i
LEFT JOIN (SELECT invoiceId, vatId, SUM(vatAmount) AS sumVatAmounts
           FROM tblinvoicesLines
           GROUP BY invoiceId, vatId) t ON t.invoiceId = i.id
GROUP BY i.id, i.dateCreated
```

Or if you really must use a subquery:

```
SELECT i.id AS invoiceId,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(sumVatAmounts)
        FROM (SELECT invoiceId, vatId, SUM(vatAmount) AS sumVatAmounts
              FROM tblinvoicesLines
              GROUP BY invoiceId, vatId) t
        WHERE t.invoiceId = i.id) AS listVatAmounts
FROM tblInvoices i
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e0097bf8eb39586f68292eaf9768a3b2)

Comment: Thank you for the effort. In my original query I must preserve the "from tblInvoices" part (for various reasons) and can't do a grouping on tblinvoicesLines they way you suggested I'm afraid. It must be achieved as a stand-alone subquery

Comment: @user2022678 can you not just `JOIN` this to `tblInvoices`? e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f0bcdbe41643fb935228652be4df9b1d

Comment: @user2022678 please see my edit. It offers a couple of other solutions, including a subquery...

Comment: thank you Nick; you edit works well!. It is rather slow performance wise though. I've just posted also a 'solution' here. Basically it is the same as yours but I've added a variable (addSign)invoiceId which I used to link with tblinvoicesLines.invoiceId for performance reasons

Comment: @Patrick yeah - that's the issue with using a subquery, you can't pass the `invoiceId` value from the top level down deep enough to use it to filter the sum. Using a variable works, but is risky and may stop working f you change the query around enough as MySQL doesn't guarantee the order of evaluation of values in the `SELECT`, so it is possible that the subquery could be evaluated before the assignment of `@invoiceId`. Still, if it's working you should accept your own answer. I still think a `JOIN`-based solution will be the best solution in the long term though...

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with one **SELECT** like this:

```
SELECT  invoiceId, CONCAT(
    SUM(IF(vatId=7,vatAmount,0))
    ,if( SUM(IF(vatId=8,vatAmount,0)) >0
        , CONCAT(',',SUM(IF(vatId=8,vatAmount,0)))
        ,'')
    ) AS listVatAmounts
FROM invoiceId
GROUP BY invoiceId;
```

OR with subquery and for all invoiceIds

```
SELECT
    invoiceId,
    GROUP_CONCAT(vatAmount ORDER BY vatId SEPARATOR ', ') AS listVatAmounts
FROM (
    SELECT id, invoiceId, vatId, SUM(vatAmount) as vatAmount
    FROM invoiceId
    GROUP BY invoiceId,vatId
    ) grp
GROUP BY invoiceId
ORDER BY id;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT  invoiceId, CONCAT(
    ->     SUM(IF(vatId=7,vatAmount,0))
    ->     ,if( SUM(IF(vatId=8,vatAmount,0)) >0
    ->         , CONCAT(',',SUM(IF(vatId=8,vatAmount,0)))
    ->         ,'')
    ->     ) AS listVatAmounts
    -> FROM invoiceId
    -> GROUP BY invoiceId;
+-----------+----------------+
| invoiceId | listVatAmounts |
+-----------+----------------+
|         4 | 47.00,15.75    |
|         5 | 10.05          |
|         6 | 11.04          |
+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.01 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

**Sample 2**

```
MariaDB [bernd]> SELECT
    ->     invoiceId,
    ->     GROUP_CONCAT(vatAmount ORDER BY vatId SEPARATOR ', ') AS listVatAmounts
    -> FROM (
    ->     SELECT id, invoiceId, vatId, SUM(vatAmount) as vatAmount
    ->     FROM invoiceId
    ->     GROUP BY invoiceId,vatId
    ->     ) grp
    -> GROUP BY invoiceId
    -> ORDER BY id;
+-----------+----------------+
| invoiceId | listVatAmounts |
+-----------+----------------+
|         4 | 47.00, 15.75   |
|         5 | 10.05          |
|         6 | 11.04          |
+-----------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [bernd]>
```

Answer (score 0):

What Ive done is the following:

```
select
@invoiceId:= tblInvoices.id as invoiceId,

(
select group_concat(vatAmount)
from
(
select sum(vatAmount) as vatAmount
from tblinvoicesLines
where tblinvoicesLines.invoiceId=@invoiceId
group by tblinvoicesLines.vatId
) t
)

as listVatAmounts

from tblInvoices
order by id desc
limit 10
```

But the performance is not very well. It does it however in one subquery